# OS X: Select menu item without dismissing

Tags: macos

I've been wondering about this for a while: is it possible to click an item in a menu and have the menu *stay put*, so you can select another item in the same menu immediately afterwards?

Perhaps a secret setting or tweak? Perhaps a plugin? Any method that would work on OS X.

This would be a very handy trick indeed!

Answer (score 0):

This seems contrary to how menus typically work. However, I'm fond for creating keyboard shortcuts. You can do his by creating application specific ones in the keyboard applet of system preferences. I'm going from memory but I think you simply select "App Shortcuts", click the "+" sign to add a new app, select the shortcut you want to use and then type out the names of the menu options, e.g. File,Open,New Tab for a browser...

**Be careful** not to use a key combo already in use or you will disable that option. HTH

Comment: Yes... I agree. Shortcuts are the way to go. But persistent menus that work by re-opening the menu to that same spot (if it's still there) doesn't seem contrary to how they work. But I suppose it isn't good practice anyway. Thanks.